# Why can't I use LOAD DATA LOCAL with PDO even though I can from cli client?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo, load-data-infile

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 10.04 dev server to 14.04. It is actually a fresh install. PHP version was 5.4.15, and is now PHP 5.5.9. MySQL went from 5.1.67 to 5.5.37.

I am trying to LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE on a new server. It works running the command using the local mysql cli client. It does not work when executing using PDO:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version' in /home/ubuntu/mysqltest.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ubuntu/mysqltest.php(21): PDO->exec('LOAD DATA LOCAL...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ubuntu/mysqltest.php on line 21
```

The code that generates the error:

```
ini_set('mysql.allow_local_infile', 1);
echo "mysql.allow_local_infile: ".ini_get("mysql.allow_local_infile").PHP_EOL;

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1);
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPassword, $options);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->exec("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table ( id INT(4), col1 varchar(128) ) ENGINE MYISAM");

$loadSQL = <<<'EOT'
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' INTO TABLE `tmp_table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (id, col1)
EOT;

$db->exec($loadSQL);
```

Steps taken so far to address problem:

- I have added local-infile = 1 to both [mysql] and [mysqld] sections of /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- I have checked that mysql.allow_local_infile = On is in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.
- DB user is root and so has all privileges.
- /tmp/test.csv does exist and user has full privileges on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in php. Please see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68226 for explanation and workaround.

Answer (score 13):

Installing php5-mysqlnd to replace php5-mysql fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

It will automatically remove php5-mysql.

I'm guessing this is a bug either in php5-mysql or the underlying libmysqlclient.

Comment: Will it affect the current database or data?

Comment: No, this only changes the driver PHP uses. Any differences would be bugs in the respective code. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

Comment: @jay.m.martin Thanks. Can confirm that this resolved my issue on 5.6.24. In 5.6.19 it works but in 5.6.24 not, even after allowing local-infile within the server config and by passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue with php 5.6.18.