# how to load data from local file in php with pdo driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, load-data-infile

I have a function that needs to load data into a mysql db from a csv file, so I wrote some code:

```
try {

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=borsino_ittico',
                   'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4",
                          PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true, 
                          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
                  );


} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
       $mex= "database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
       return $mex;
    }
```

other code

```
try {
    $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($file)." INTO TABLE ".
            $pdo->quote($dbTable)." FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n,\\n'");

    $mex= "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";
    return $mex;

} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
        $mex= "ATTENZIONE, ERRORE CARICAMENTO DATI: ".$e->getMessage();
        return $mex;
}
```

Actually this doesn't seem to works and threw an exception:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''asta' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ,\n'' at line 1

First question is about $file (the resource):
should be in absolute/relative form (likes c:\xxx\csvfile.csv or ..\xxx\csvfile.csv) or I've to expose it with a function likes `$csvFile=fopen($file,"r");`

Then, should I use pdo native function likes `$pdo->quote()` for insert arguments (like the file,table name, separator, lines terminated by) on the $affectedRows query?

How can I force the esecution of the query even with some errors on some row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quoting your table name, producing

```
... INTO table 'asta' ...
```

`'`-quotes turn things into a strings. So `asta` is no longer a table name, it's just a string with the letters `a`, `s`, etc...

Identifiers must be quoted with backticks:

```
... INTO table `asta` ...
               ^----^---
```

Comment: I quoted as suggested the table name ASTA and then I rised this new exception`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Comment: should be enabled it from php.ini or somewhere else?

Comment: no. it's a mysql setting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html

Comment: from some other post i found that `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,`  should solve the problem...but it doesn't work!

Comment: I found this solutions thats seem to works (now I've errors but from the data into the file :) ) [workaround solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525111/why-cant-i-use-load-data-local-with-pdo-even-though-i-can-from-cli-client)

Answer (score 0):

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n,\\n'
```

doesn't work for me!!!! after many test the only solution is to remove the double escaped `\\n`

So

```
`LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`
```

works even if somewhere I read about the needs of "escape" the "\" simbol for PHP.